# Getting rid of CORS policy error with MEAN stack app (hosted on Heroku)

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, express, cors

I've been working on a MEAN stack app for a little while, and for the past month I've been wrestling with this CORS policy error:

"Access to XMLHTTPRequest at <my heroku app url.com/login> from origin  has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' has a value:  that is not equal to the supplied origin."

I have had *some* success with getting it to work on *some* devices. After messing around with request/response header settings in my middleware functions in my server.js file and POST requests in my services that communicate with the backend, I have gotten it to work on my desktop (Windows 10), on my Ubuntu OS on my desktop, on my laptop (Windows 10), on my friends macbook, etc.

However, I'm still getting CORS policy issues on some of my friends devices. There doesn't seem to be anything in common with what devices work and what devices don't (different OS's do and don't work, when it doesn't work it's across all browsers).

It also might be worth noting, that on devices that get the CORS error, the page for my app says 'not secure' in the top right, where on the devices where it does work it's labelled as secure.

Things I've done:

- imported the cors module in my server.js file
- tried using the csp (content security policy) module
- modified headers to the requests to my server
- modified headers to the responses sent from the server back to the client
- a lot of googling and fiddling around with CORS policy settings

I'm also using passport and bcrypt for user authentication, if that's relevant.

Here's the relevant server.js code:

```
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
//var csp = require('content-security-policy');
var app = express();
var dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();

var url = require('url');

var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session'); // should give us persistent sessions...
var passport = require('passport');
var ejs = require('ejs');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
var flash = require('express-flash');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var path = require('path');
//const env = require('./src/environments/environment');
//const methodOverride = require('method-override')
//var initializePassport = require('passport-config');
var initializePassport = require('./passport-config');
// this completes passport authentication strategy
// passes passport, a function for finding a user by their username,
// and a function for finding a user by id to the initialize() function inside passport-config
// the authenticateUser function then uses these methods to get what it needs
var connurl = '';
if(process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development'){
  connurl = 'http://localhost:4200';
}
else{
  connurl = 'https://to-do-bentancock.herokuapp.com';
}

initializePassport(
  passport,
  // both of these things are functions, passed into passport config
  // I think I pass mongoose middleware stuff here to return the right things
  username => Users.find({username: { $eq: username }}),
  id => Users.find({id: { $eq: id }})
)

var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
var router = express.Router();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(cookieParser('process.env.SECRET'));

var cspPolicy = {
  'default-src': 'self, https://to-do-bentancock.herokuapp.com/*',
  'img-src': '*',
}

/*app.use(csp({
  policies: {
    'default-src': [csp.NONE],
    'img-src': [csp.SELF],
  }
}));

const globalCSP = csp.getCSP(cspPolicy);
app.use(globalCSP)

*/

app.use(session({
  secret: 'process.env.SECRET',
  resave: true, // should we reset our session variables if nothing has changed?
  // NOTE: this MUST be set to true otherwise the user authentication / session data won't be saved between middleware methods
  // e.g. if you log in (via /tasks post method), it will print the session data at the end, but if you then do '/create' method right after the req object will be null (because it wasn't saved)
  saveUninitialized: true, // do you want to save an empty value in the session if there is no value?
  cookie: {
    // might want to look into changing this in the future, as cookie stores user stuff
    // for now I have it off until I'm certain I've got all this passport js, cookie and session stuff down pat
    secure: false,
    maxAge: 600000
  },
  store: new MongoStore({
    mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection,
    ttl: 60 * 60, // keeps the session open for 1 hour
    collection: 'sessions'
  })
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(cors({credentials: true, origin: true}));

// enables pre-flight requests across the board
app.options('*', cors()) // include before other routes

app.get('/with-cors', cors(), (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("testing cors:");
});

app.use('/', express.query());

app.get('/*', function(req,res) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", connurl);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  //res.header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  console.log("here's what app.get is receiving: " + req.url);
  console.log("sending file!");
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/to-do-heroku/index.html'));
});

app.post('/loginCheck', function(req, res){
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", connurl);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  res.header('Content-Type', 'application/json');

  console.log("res header: %j", res.getHeaders());
  console.log("\nlogin check");
  if(req.isAuthenticated()){
    console.log("authentication returns true!");
    //console.log("printing req passport data: ");
    //console.log(req.session);
    //console.log(req.user);
    //res.headersSent();
    res.send({authenticated: true});
  }
  else{
    console.log("user is not authenticated");
    res.send({authenticated: false});
  }
});

app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", connurl);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  res.header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  console.log("res header: %j", res.getHeaders());
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    console.log("printing error: " + err);
    console.log("passport info: " + JSON.stringify(info)); // undefined
    if(err){
      console.log("error authenticating!");
      res.send({status: 'error logging in user'});
      return;
    }

    if(!err){
      req.logIn(user, function(err){
        if(err){
          console.log("error logging in");
          //return
        }
        res.send({status: 'success'});
      });
    }
  })(req, res, next);
});

app.post('/logout', checkAuthenticated, async function(req, res){
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", connurl);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  res.header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  console.log("\nlogging out user");
  await req.logout(); // logOut or logout??
  res.send({status: 'redirect', url: '/login'});
});


app.post('/getTasks', checkAuthenticated, function(req, res){
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", connurl);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    console.log("\n Successful authentication, request: " + JSON.stringify(req.body));

    Users.find({id: { $eq: req.session.passport.user}}, function(err, doc){
      if(!doc.length || doc == null){ // if the user is not found
        console.log("ERROR: USER NOT FOUND, LOGGING OUT");
        req.logOut();
        res.send({error:'not found'}); // send some kind of message back to client-side
      }
      else{
        res.send({tasks: doc[0].tasks, idCount: doc[0].idCount});
      }

    });
});



var uri = '';
if(process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development'){
  uri = 'mongodb://localhost/todoDB'
}
else{
  uri = "mongodb+srv://todoApp:7211@cluster0.huawl.mongodb.net/toDoDB?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
}


//const uri = "mongodb+srv://todoApp:7211@cluster0.huawl.mongodb.net/toDoDB?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
mongoose.connect(uri);
const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once('open', function(){
  mongoose.connection.db.collection('usersCollection').countDocuments(function(err, docs){
    console.log("there are " + docs + " docs in the collection\n");
  });
  console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully\n");
});

function checkAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    console.log("user is authenticated!");
    return next();
  }
  console.log("WARNING: USER NOT AUTHENTICATED");
  res.send({authenticated: false});
}

function checkNotAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    console.log("\nuser IS authenticated, stopping this request...");
    // Send a message back to the client telling it to redirect instead
    //res.send({authenticated: true});
    return;
  }
  //res.send({authenticated: false});
  console.log("user is NOT authenticated");
  next();
}



if(process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development'){
  app.listen(4000, function(req, res){
    console.log("express server listening on port 4000");
  });
}
else{
  app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, function(req, res){
    console.log("express server listening on port 8080");
  });

}
```

And here is the code for the services that communicate with server.js:

auth.service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { environment } from './../environments/environment';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  url = environment.apiUrl;


  username;
  password;
  loggedIn = false;



  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) { }

  login(uname, pw){
    console.log("logging in user: " + uname + " " + pw + '\n');
    console.log("the url: " + this.url);
    this.username = uname;
    this.password = pw;
    return this.http.post(this.url + '/login', {username: uname, password: pw}, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' : 'true',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "*" // this might just need to be the api url
      }),
      withCredentials: true
    });
  }

  setLogin(bool){
    this.loggedIn = bool;
  }

  logout(){
    console.log("test auth logout");
    return this.http.post(this.url + '/logout', {body: 'logout'},  {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' : 'true',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "*"
      }),
      withCredentials: true
    });
  }

  loginCheck(){
    console.log("test auth service login check");
    return this.http.post(this.url + '/loginCheck', {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' : 'true',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "*"
      }),
      withCredentials: true
    });
  }


  registerUser(uname, pw){
    console.log("registering user: " + uname + " " + pw + '\n');

    // the object sent needs to be a user object, which contains task objects
    // new user won't have any tasks tho (obvi)
    // also need to check for duplicate usernames
    return this.http.post(this.url + '/register',
    {
      username: uname,
      password: pw,
      idCount: 0,
      id: Date.now().toString(),
      tasks: []
    },
    {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' : 'true',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "*"
      }),
      withCredentials: true
    });
  }


  // takes user tasks data as input, passes it to tasks component
  renderTasks(){
    console.log("render tasks \n");
    this.router.navigate(['/tasks']);
  }
```

task.service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, tap, share, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { environment } from './../environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TasksService {
  //url = 'http://localhost:4000' // the port the mongo database is listening on
  //url = 'https://to-do-bentancock.herokuapp.com';
  url = environment.apiUrl;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }


  getTasks(userName, pw){
    console.log("tasks service: get tasks \n");
    console.log("username and pw to post: " + userName + " " + pw);

    return this.http.post(this.url + '/getTasks', {username: userName, password: pw},
    {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' : 'true',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "*"
      }),
      withCredentials: true
    });
  }

  deleteTask(uname, pw, id: number ){
    var delUrl = this.url + "/deleteTask/" + id;

    return this.http.post(delUrl, {username: uname, password: pw},
      {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' : 'true',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "*"
        }),
        withCredentials: true
      }
    );

  }

  /*
  a task object has a:
  - name
  - date
  - description
  - priority
  - id
  */
  createTask(uname, pw, task){
    console.log("test create task (service)");

    // send user data, and a task object
    return this.http.post(this.url + '/create',
    {
      task:
      {
        name: task.name,
        date: task.date,
        description: task.description,
        priority: task.priority,
        id: task.id,
        state: task.state
      },
      user:
      {
        username: uname,
        password: pw
      }
    },
    {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' : 'true',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "*"
      }),
      withCredentials: true
    }
  );
  }
```

I've been googling and troubleshooting this forever and I'm pretty burnt out. Does anyone have any advice? What am I missing?

Answer (score -1):

I'm just use `app.use(cors())`  without `app.options('*', cors())` and `cors()` inside your get